# Passing the port in WebSocket Requests of Postman Beta Feature

Tags: tcp, postman

I used the new https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/supported-api-frameworks/websocket/ of postman to check a TCP connectivity to a  remote host.

Using Test-NetConnection I got to know that the connection is successful.

```
Test-NetConnection 138.149.1.1 -Port 6021
```

The connectivity is failing and I am wondering was it due to misplaced port.
I passed the port like this .
[image]

Also I tried to send it as a Header parameter and a normal parameter , yet no avail .Any help is appreciated since this is a **Beta** feature of Postman.
Also I tried  below too.

hostname:port